# Div stay during scroll. CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, scroll

I want to do div "Scroll" which stay in one place, even during scroll. Here's my code :

```css
.Scroll {
  position: fixed;
}
.Down {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="Scroll">
    <div class="Down">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;">
        <h4><small>Select Date From <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></small></h4>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" />
        <h4><small>Select Date To <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></small> </h4>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" style="width:250px;" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Down">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>DATE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="name in names">
        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
        <td>{{name.date}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position:absolute` instead of `position:fixed` like below:

```
.Scroll {
  /*position: fixed;*/
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: It don't work ;/ @Fateh singh Jagdeo

Answer (score 0):

You need to have enough content to scroll or you're not going to be able to scroll. 
The following css is what I used:

```
.Scroll {
display:block;
  position: fixed;
  top:100;
  left:100;
  background:#fff;
}
.Down {
  clear: both;
}
```

See my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/e63eyswp/1/